# Jenkins - Passing variable password to external shell

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using the BUILD STEP "Execute shell script on remote host" and I'm injecting a password to my project:

[image]

The jenkins call a `script.sh`, but the script does not print variable `PASS` passed by [jenkins](/questions/tagged/jenkins).
As a step variable issued by Jenkins to my external script?

```
PASS=${PASSWORD}
echo PASSWORD=$PASS
sh /root/script.sh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `export` your variable in order to make it available to subshells:

```
export PASS=${PASSWORD}
```

If you don't want other programs you invoke in the same script to see your password, consider this safer way:

```
PASS=${PASSWORD} /root/script.sh
```